# Finding the greatest four digit number

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can this problem be solved using Chinese remainder theorem? If yes, how to use it?
I have not used the Chinese remainder theorem in any problems and I'm unaware of how to use it in these types of problems though I know about the theorem. So, please help.

Thanks in advance- Rajath

Answer (score 6):

You're after the greatest $n \leq 9999$ that satisfies $$n \equiv -2 \pmod {\mathrm{lcm}(3,5,7,9)}$$ that is $$n \equiv -2 \pmod {315}.$$  It is $9763$.

Comment: How did you get that -2 there?

Comment: In each case there's a $-2$ residue: $1 \equiv -2 \pmod 3$, $3 \equiv -2 \pmod 5$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Let the number be a then by the given conditions we have

$a=3p+1=3(p+1)-2$, similarly

$a=5(q+1)-2$

$a=7(r+1)-2$

$a=9(s+1)-2$

Hence, $a$ is of the form $a=(L.C.M(3,5,7,9))(k+1)-2=315(k+1)-2$

But $a\leq9999$ or $315(k+1)-2\leq9999$ which gives us $k=30$.

Hence $a =315(30+1)-2=9763$.